# Canvas objects not disappearing when out of scope

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following code that every so often creates a canvas, puts an image of a bulb on it and changes all the yellow pixels to a colour that is passed in. When the colour of the bulb changes you are still able to see all the old canvas objects in the console in safari under the canvas tab. Does this mean they are taking up memory? Should they not disappear when they go out of scope (When the colour changes and a new bulb is used)?

```
// Set colour of light bulb
function set_bulb_colour(img_id, rgb_colour)
{
    // Load the light bulb image in and redraw it with the new colour
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function()
    {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < image_data.data.length; i += 4)
        {
            // If the pixel is yellow set it to the new colour
            if (image_data.data[i + 3] != 0 && (image_data.data[i] > 200 && image_data.data[i + 2] < 100))
            {
                image_data.data[i] = rgb_colour[0];
                image_data.data[i + 1] = rgb_colour[1];
                image_data.data[i + 2] = rgb_colour[2];
            }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);

        // Set the image src to the bulb with the new colour
        $(img_id).attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());
    }

    img.src = 'images/light_bulb.png';
}
```

Here you can see that there are multiple canvas', the purple and red ones have gone and the pink one is now displayed, but the red and purple ones aren't disappearing, are they using up memory? Every time the colour changes a new canvas is added to the queue, I expected the older ones to be removed. Hope I explained that ok.

edit: `imd_id` is always the same at the minute, so the new image just replaces the old one.

[image]

Comment: You're creating canvases every time. Remove your canvas after you set image source.

Comment: Well I think that is the intrinsic question right? Once the function no longer holds a reference to that variable, shouldn't it be garbage collected. We don't have enough code or a working sample to determine an answer to _that_ question. But, if the OP wants direct control, the OP needs to remove the canvas element from the DOM and set `canvas` to `null`.

Comment: I cannot answer why they are each in the view because, well...We don't have enough code or a working sample to determine an answer to that question

Comment: There isn't really anymore code, a php script gets colour data from smart lights in my house every 10 secs, when I get the data I call this function to draw the image the same colour as the smart light. Ill try setting it to null now. (edit) Setting to null doesnt seem to have an effect.

Comment: I used this jsfiddle that I found on here to help with my solution, if you open the console and go to the canvas tab you can see the same happening, even when setting the canvas to null after. http://jsfiddle.net/pandey_mohit/BeSwL/